# Paypal Payment method for

Tags: php, paypal

Is there any Paypal Payment method or Paypal PHP API for doing...

Site user can withdraw money from admin paypal account to user paypal account without admin permission (or paypal login).

Like, User click a button from his dashboard "withdraw $10 now" then system automatically transfer $10 from admin paypal account to user paypal account.

If one time admin permission (or paypal login) is ask then it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yon neet to use [Payouts](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/tree/master/sample/payouts) area of [REST API](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK). For a single withdrawal take look [CreateSinglePayout.php](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payouts/CreateSinglePayout.php).

Comment: Thanks, This is very helpful.